# AFNetworking addOperation getting locked

Tags: ios, multithreading, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue

I'm using AFNetworking 1.3.3 and running into an issue i'm unsure how to debug. Below is the stack trace. The issue so far only reproduce during unit test, but that probably points to a design issue that will cause issue at some other "random" times, so I want to figure it out.

Below is the stack trace, there is no output in the log and the app just stay there. It seems to me that the app is in dead lock, but i can't figure out why it would be.

Edit: one detail i missed is that the execution pointed indicates:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code = 1, address=xxxxxx)
```

Any pointers appreciated, thanks, olivier

```
Thread 1, Queue : com.apple.main-thread
#0  0x0409e0b2 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x030316d4 in NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationLocal ()
#2  0x0302f79f in NSKeyValueWillChange ()
#3  0x03005d1a in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] ()
#4  0x0303560c in __addOperations ()
#5  0x03034f0e in -[NSOperationQueue addOperation:] ()
#6  0x0025cab7 in -[AFHTTPClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:] at /Users/olivier/Documents/elektra/src/elektra/third_party/AFNetworking-1.3.3/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m:577
#7  0x00091598 in -[ELEDataObjectSync startConnectionWithPath:parameters:HTTPBody:HTTPMethod:] at /Users/olivier/Documents/elektra/src/elektra/elektra/data_sync/ELEDataObjectSync.m:215
#8  0x0020e762 in -[ELELoginRequest loginUser:withPassword:withCompletionBlock:] at /Users/olivier/Documents/elektra/src/elektra/elektra/data_sync/ELELoginRequest.m:34
#9  0x0023542d in -[ELEUserManager loginUser:withPassword:withCompletionBlock:] at /Users/olivier/Documents/elektra/src/elektra/elektra/user/ELEUserManager.m:74
#10 0x0be94179 in +[ELEUserManager(unitTestUtilities) signInUser:withPassword:] at /Users/olivier/Documents/elektra/src/elektra/elektra/user/ELEUserManager+unitTestUtilities.m:20
#11 0x0be9e5e5 in -[ELEUserAccountRequestTest setUp] at /Users/olivier/Documents/elektra/src/elektra/elektraTests/ELEUserAccountRequestTest.m:27
#12 0x20103266 in -[XCTestCase invokeTest] ()
#13 0x2010338d in -[XCTestCase performTest:] ()
#14 0x2010417c in -[XCTest run] ()
#15 0x20102a44 in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
#16 0x2010417c in -[XCTest run] ()
#17 0x20102a44 in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
#18 0x2010417c in -[XCTest run] ()
#19 0x20102a44 in -[XCTestSuite performTest:] ()
#20 0x2010417c in -[XCTest run] ()
#21 0x20105aa1 in +[XCTestProbe runTests:] ()
#22 0x0301612c in __NSFireDelayedPerform ()
#23 0x042c9bd6 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#24 0x042c95bd in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
#25 0x042b1628 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#26 0x042b0ac3 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#27 0x042b08db in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#28 0x045659e2 in GSEventRunModal ()
#29 0x04565809 in GSEventRun ()
#30 0x0214dd3b in UIApplicationMain ()
#31 0x0000628b in main at /Users/olivier/Documents/elektra/src/elektra/elektra/main.m:49

Thread 2, Queue : com.apple.libdispatch-manager
#0  0x04ac2992 in kevent64 ()
#1  0x046eaf3e in _dispatch_mgr_invoke ()
#2  0x046eac7a in _dispatch_mgr_thread ()

Thread 3, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 4, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 5, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 6, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 7, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04abcf7a in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x04abc16c in mach_msg ()
#2  0x042abe49 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x042b13b1 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x042b0ac3 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x042b08db in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x0303c9c5 in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] ()
#7  0x02fd88d1 in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] ()
#8  0x0036660b in +[TFURLConnectionOperation _runNetworkThread:] ()
#9  0x03037597 in -[NSThread main] ()
#10 0x030374f6 in __NSThread__main__ ()
#11 0x04a845fb in _pthread_body ()
#12 0x04a84485 in _pthread_start ()

Thread 8 com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04abcf7a in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x04abc16c in mach_msg ()
#2  0x042abe49 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x042b13b1 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x042b0ac3 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x042b08db in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x02fdb9de in +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] ()
#7  0x03037597 in -[NSThread main] ()
#8  0x030374f6 in __NSThread__main__ ()
#9  0x04a845fb in _pthread_body ()
#10 0x04a84485 in _pthread_start ()

Thread 9, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 10, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 11, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 12, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 13, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 14, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 15 AFNetworking, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04abcf7a in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x04abc16c in mach_msg ()
#2  0x042abe49 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x042b13b1 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x042b0ac3 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x042b08db in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#6  0x0303c9c5 in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] ()
#7  0x02fd88d1 in -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] ()
#8  0x00087fbb in +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] at /Users/olivier/Documents/elektra/src/elektra/third_party/AFNetworking-1.3.3/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m:184
#9  0x03037597 in -[NSThread main] ()
#10 0x030374f6 in __NSThread__main__ ()
#11 0x04a845fb in _pthread_body ()
#12 0x04a84485 in _pthread_start ()

Thread 16 com.apple.CFSocket.private, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac1ace in select$DARWIN_EXTSN ()
#1  0x042ef3eb in __CFSocketManager ()
#2  0x04a845fb in _pthread_body ()
#3  0x04a84485 in _pthread_start ()

Thread 17, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 18, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()

Thread 19, Queue : (null)
#0  0x04ac2046 in __workq_kernreturn ()
#1  0x04a85dcf in _pthread_wqthread ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to this post: [EXC_BAD_ACCESS error thrown in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222675/exc-bad-access-error-thrown-in-xcode)

It turns out to not be a deadlock but an object that had been released and then messaged. 
I though zombies were enabled, but they were not enabled for my test target. Once i enabled those it was easy to figure out the issue.